# system build research

Tags: opencl, gpu, hypervisor

I'm in the research phase of my next computer build. I have the idea in my head of running a hypervisor as the base of the system, but i would want to be able to take a shot at programming opencl with one of the OS's installed on the hypervisor...and maybe some gaming. Would i have enough access to the GPU to be able to achieve this effectively, or am i better off installing an OS that i will do development(and gaming) from and then just virtualize any systems on top of that?

what are your recommendations for a hypervisor, vmware, microsoft or other?

*sidenote:* Recently graduated with a BS in CS, the massive parallel processing seems like a good idea of something to learn, won't be doing any 'real'/major development work. also, i'm aware that CUDA is more mature in it's development, but i'm sticking with opencl for a few reasons, so please don't try to persuade me.

thanks for your input!
dave k.

Answer (score 1):

whats your focus? Virtualisation or OpenCL?

Hak5 did a nice walkthrough of debian based virtualisation environment [ProxMox](http://www.hak5.org/episodes/episode-820), but I don't know whether it allows virtual hosts hardware access or OpenCL virtualisation.

Comment: i plan on it being a multipurpose machine, so using virtualization for different enviroments that i would be running concurrently. ie. a file server for general local stuff, possibly a webserver, development, testing, everyday use.